# Equation in a yellow box

Tags: equations, tcolorbox

I'm trying to insert a numbered equation inside a yellow box. The problem is that the yellow box extends across the entire line. How can I avoid it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
colback=yellow!40!white,
sharp corners
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{mybox}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to achieve is to place a formula in a colored box, employing the machinery of the `tcolorbox` may be overkill. For sure, using the `\colorbox` macro of the [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor) package would require far less overhead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for '\colorbox' macro
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\colorbox{yellow!40!white}{$\displaystyle ~a = b~\vphantom{\int}$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

(I trust you can figure out what `\vphantom{\int}` and `~` are doing. If not, please let me know and I'll provide an explanation.)

Comment: Hi @Mico elegant solution. Can you tell me the meaning of \vphantom{\int} and ~ please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi - `\vphantom{\int}` inserts a (typographic) strut with the height and depth of a (displaystyle-size) integral symbol; this serves to create some vertical "padding" for the material that's enclosed by `\colorbox`. The `~` symbols insert a bit of horizontal whitespace; thus, inserting `~` at both the start and end of the formula serves to create a bit of horizontal padding for what's enclosed by `\colorbox`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @Mico

Answer (score 5):

With `empheq` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
{\setlength\fboxsep{3ex}
\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{yellow}]{equation}
a = b 
\end{empheq}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: Size of yellow box is determined by border around equation. It is  defined by  `fboxsep`. You can determine it locally as is done in above MWE or globally, if you move `\setlength\fboxsep{3ex}` to the document preamble. You may find other `fboxsep` size more appropriate, for example 2ex, which gives:

[image]

Comment: great alternative @Zarko

Comment: @Mico, done. Thank you very much for the comment!

Comment: +1 for the update

Answer (score 4):

Probably the output is closer to the expected one, when using `\tcbhighmath`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{highlight math/.append style={boxrule=0pt,
                                      frame hidden,
                                      colback=yellow!40!white,
                                      sharp corners}}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{a=b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @leandriis thank you for your useful solution